# AutoCAD C# call quick select dialog from new my form

Tags: c#, autocad, autocad-plugin, quickselect

Does anyone know how to show quick select dialog by click on button on my new autocad form.

I use SendStringToExecute method, but it sends the command after closed the dialog

```
AcadApp.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument.SendStringToExecute("__QSELECT", true, true, false);
```

the above code dose not work, any one can help
thanks to all

Comment: You'd have to hide the form first as I'm assuming it's modal.

Comment: Autocad 2014 @Maxence

Answer (score 1):

I think this is not possible. You cannot run a command while a modal dialog box is displayed.

You can try to hide (`Editor.StartUserInteraction`) it and use a synchronous way to send a command to AutoCAD (like P/Invoke of `acedCmd`) but I've tried it and it crashes AutoCAD.

Typically, calling an AutoCAD command is a bad idea. .NET is not AutoLISP.

You can implement an interface similar to the QSELECT command and use it from your dialog box.

Comment: Even if you found a way to do it I'd be surprised if it was robust. In my experience that sort of thing leads to all sorts of mysterious crashes and weird unexplained errors.

Answer (score 0):

Add a space after the _QSELECT. Something like:

```
Document autocadDocument = autocadDocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument;
autocadDocument.SendStringToExecute("_QSELECT ", false, false, true);
```

Or make your own QSELECT interface. That could be fun too.